# MYSQL Database connection for php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using my website database with php mysql_connect but my hosting provider is saying I need to use mysqli_connect.

When I edit connection file and update change method its not working with mysqli.

Currently using this code:

MSQL Method:

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("databasename");
```

and for mysqli I am using this code but fail

MYSQLI Method:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

Please help. Why is mysqli not working? Is my method wrong?

Comment: fails how? what error? Did you convert all your code to mysqli not just the connection

Comment: Is it possible that your a) mysql server is not running b) your given username does not exist c) your password is wrong?

Comment: Why did you change the username, password, and database name?

Comment: You can't just change the connect method. You'll have to update every use of a `mysql_` function to use the equivalent `mysqli_` version instead. Some of those updates are pretty straightforward, others not so much.

Comment: did u check connection ? `if ($con) ? echo 'ok'; : echo 'fail'; `

Comment: @Mario It helps to use full words here, as "u" can trip up automatic translation tools that people depend on to understand English.

Comment: If your error message is just an warning or notice and website working fine then just suppress the error message and first convert everthing into `mysqli` not just connection. `mysql` is deprecated but your server must work with mysql too

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Example (MySQLi Object-Oriented)

```
 <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
`   $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";
    ?>
```

Example (MySQLi Procedural)

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password,  $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```